# Changing date format in SSIS

Tags: mysql, oracle, ssis, date-format

I am trying to move data from chinook db(oracle) to chinook DW(mysql) using SSIS. 
Currently in my oracle db I have a date format(07-AUG-11) and want since I need to put in MYSQL(2011-08-07) but I am not able to do it.

I tried using this in oracle for conversion

```
 select to_char(to_date(InvoiceDate,'DD-MON-YY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') from CHINOOK.invoice;
```

and tried using the expression(from to_char onwards) in SSIS but did not work.
(there are also other expressions I tried but SSIS throws error saying the function does not exist)

I just need to know whats the expression in SSIS.If anyone could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bring it into SSIS as a date, using (in Oracle):

```
TO_DATE(InvoiceDate,'DD-MON-YY')
```

Then if you need to convert it into a string with the 'yyyy-MM-dd' format, you can use something like (in SSIS):

```
(DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR(DateField) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH(DateField), 2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(DateField), 2)
```

Although, if your destination is a date field, then it should go straight in without any processing/transformation as it is a date already.